# long to baseX alphanumeric code issues

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following SQL function - it is called as a Trigger on a table Insert. I have a requirement to convert the ID to an alphanumericID that only contains certain characters:

```
USE [NewCo]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fnBase10ToBase32]    Script Date: 16/07/2015 06:51:36 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER function [dbo].[fnBase10ToBase32]
(
@val as BigInt
)
returns varchar(7)
as
Begin

--TAKEN FROM http://geekswithblogs.net/bbiales/archive/2009/05/04/131732.aspx 2013-12-01

--Overflow at @val > 9,223,372,035,775,033,983
  --bigint MAX = 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
  --offset = 1,079,741,824
  --Biggest 7Char @val = 33,279,996,543(ZZZZZZZ)

  DECLARE @Base int = 32
  DECLARE @OffSet int = 1079741824
  /*
   (minimum for 7 chars = 1073741824)
    but - 1073741824 means @val of 1 = 2000002 - TOO many 0's so increase offset
  */


  SET @val += @OffSet

  /* Check if value is valid and if we get a valid base (2 through 36) */
  If (@val<0) return Null;

  /* variable to hold final answer */
  Declare @answer as varchar(7);

  /* Following variable contains all 
     possible alpha numeric letters for any valid base 
  */

  Declare @alldigits as varchar(32);
  Set @alldigits='023456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPRSTUVWXYZ'

  /* Set the initial value of 
     final answer as empty string 
  */
  Set @answer='';

  /* Loop while the source value remains greater than 0 */
  While @val>0
  Begin
    Set @answer=Substring(@alldigits,@val % @Base + 1,1) + @answer;
    Set @val = @val / @Base;
  End

  /* Return the final answer */
  return REVERSE(@answer);

End
```

NOTE: The above works fine (or seems to anyway).

I now need to move this functionality to C#. I have written the below but it doesn't give the same results as the SQL function and it results in an outOfRange exception when (val % baseNo = 31). I tried to set baseNo to 31 to avoid the outOfRange exception but the results are still not the same:

```
int baseNo = 32-1;
int offset = 1079741824;

long val = ProdID + offset;

if (val < 0)
{
    return null;
}

/* variable to hold final answer */
string reg = string.Empty;

//char[] alldigits = new char[] { '0', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
string alldigitsString = "023456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPRSTUVWXYZ";

/* Loop while the source value remains greater than 0 */
while (val > 0)
{

    reg = alldigitsString.Substring((int)(val % baseNo) + 1, 1) + reg;
    val = val / (baseNo + 1);
}

/* Return the final answer */
char[] arr = reg.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(arr);
return new string(arr);
```

Below are the results from the different functions:

```
ID      SQL         C#
57596   "WLVS602"   "DGVZ833"
57597   "XLVS602"   "EGVZ833"
57598   "YLVS602"   "FGVZ833"
57599   "ZLVS602"   "GGVZ833"
57600   "0MVS602"   "HHVZ833"
```

As you can see, the pattern is the same, but the numbers are different

Can anyone see where/why my results are different? I would like to stick to the SQL function results but in C# code.

I've not tried but I guess I could change the offset to make the results the same - but why would it be different?

Comment: Is the missing `1` in `allDigits` intentional? In any case, strings (and arrays) are zero based in C# - that's why 32 doesn't work for you, and that's probably also why the results are different.

Comment: Hi, yes, the missing 1 is intentional - I'm avoiding numbers that can be misread as letters (except 0). Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array and string indices are zero-based in C#.

```
const int baseNo = 32;
const int offset = 1079741824;
const string allDigits = "023456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPRSTUVWXYZ";

if (val < 0) return null;

long val = ProdID + offset;

var data = new char[255];
var index = 0;

while (val > 0)
{
    data[index++] = allDigits[(int)(val % baseNo)];
    val /= baseNo;
}

return new string(data, 0, index);
```

I've also taken the liberty of avoiding some common performance pitfals, and clearing up the code (getting rid of some of the SQL-based limitations). It looks a bit more like C# now :)

You can use whatever maximum size your ID field is in the database for the size of the `char[]` I'm creating - or if you want to be more precise, `(int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(val, baseNo)) + 1` will work to give you almost exactly as many characters as you need.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. I've just got to work and this is a "Home project" so I'll test later and mark as answer if all is well.